# Why my earlier script versions are run one by one, instead of running the last one?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vite, inertiajs

I am working on an Inertia-Vite project, and suddenly noticed, that when I am interacting with the application, the earlier versions of scripts are run one by one, instead of running only the last one. If it involves XHR request, the a lot of request is sent to the server, instead of one. Here is an image of such script, where the time portion is marked. There are many of such versions of the same files with different timing information :
[image]

I do not understand this phenomena, and I did not find relevant information about this issue.

How to avoid those earlier script versions to run?

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)